# Select list with child element removed/filtered using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to create a XPath such that it selects a list of nodes and additionally filters some data for example

```
<A>
  <B type="typea">
    <data>
      <nodea>a</nodea>
      <nodeb>b</nodeb>
      <nodec>c</nodec>
    </data>
  </B>
  <B type="typeb">
    <data1>
      <nodea1>a1</nodea1>
      <nodeb1>b1</nodeb1>
      <nodec1>c1</nodec1>
      <noded1>d1</noded1>
    </data1>
  </B>
  <B type="typec">
    <data2>
      <nodeb2>b2</nodeb2>
      <nodec2>c2</nodec2>
    </data2>
  </B>
</A>
```

gets converted to

```
  <B type="typea">
    <data>
      <nodea>a</nodea>
      <nodeb>b</nodeb>
      <nodec>c</nodec>
    </data>
  </B>
  <B type="typeb">
    <data1>
      <nodea1>a1</nodea1>
      <nodeb1>b1</nodeb1>
    </data1>
  </B>
  <B type="typec">
    <data2>
      <nodeb2>b2</nodeb2>
      <nodec2>c2</nodec2>
    </data2>
  </B>
```

I tried using `/A/B[@type='typea' or @type='typeb' or @type='typec']`, but could not find a way to filter child elements of a particular node. 
Is there a way to filter out data of node B (type="typeb") using XPath.

Comment: Right now your XPATH reads: within A find all B that have one of the following type attributes typea, typeb, typec. If you just want to exclude typeb you could drop that from the XPATH you have. What output are you trying to get? Unless you are trying to exclude nodec1 and noded1 from typeb?

Answer (score 0):

You can only select whole subtrees using XPath (no matter which version), not modify them/construct new ones. Creating new results requires XSLT or XQuery.

Using XQuery, you can select the nodes to filter and remove them using XQuery Update (if supported), otherwise you will have to loop over the nodes and recreate all of them but the ones you want to filter out.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a single XPATH, but XSLT to do what you are asking:

```

```
<xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/A/B[@type='typea' or @type='typeb' or @type='typec']">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[name() = 'nodec1' or name() = 'noded1']">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./*|./text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

```

Note that your existing XPATH is used as the base selector, and then two templates take care of processing it. The first performs "no output" on nodes of type `nodec1` or `noded1` anywhere in the XML; the second copies everything else.